# How to save a .gif in Classic ASP - converting from PHP script - options for fopen, fwrite

Tags: php, asp-classic

I have this very tiny php script which does exactly what I need - I need to convert it to classic ASP however.  I have googled but been unable to find information on anything similar to 'fopen' or 'fwrite' in classic ASP.

My original PHP Script is:

```
<?php
$responseImg = file_get_contents("http://url.to/the/api/thatreturnsagif");
$fp = fopen("/my/server/public_html/mydirectory/samepicture.gif", "w");
fwrite($fp, $responseImg);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Really short, really simple and does just what I need.  It makes a call to an API that returns a gif.  I save the gif on my local server and a cron-job runs the script every so often to keep the gif up to date.

I'm moving to an IIS server which does *not* have php on it, so classic ASP will have to suffice.

I've gotten this far:

```
<% 
url = "http://url.to/the/api/thatreturnsagif"
set xmlhttp = server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false 
xmlhttp.send "" 
Response.write xmlhttp.responseText 
set xmlhttp = nothing 
%>
```

I was able to put that together from some other stuff online.

I just need to figure out how to save the gif that will be returned on the server - then I will setup scheduled tasks to run it on an interval.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_ref_filesystem.asp

Comment: Here's a thread which may be of some help - https://bytes.com/topic/asp-classic/answers/167700-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-response-binarywrite  I think you'll definitely need to be using response.binarywrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xmlhttp` (instance of IServerXMLHTTPRequest) has a method [responseBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753682%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that returns array of bytes, use it instead of `responseText`.
Then write into a stream and save as file.

```vb
url = "http://url.to/the/api/thatreturnsagif"
set xmlhttp = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0") 
xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false 
xmlhttp.send
With Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
    .Type = 1 '1 for binary stream
    .Open
    .Write xmlhttp.responseBody
    .SaveToFile Server.Mappath("\mydirectory\samepicture.gif"), 2 ' 2 for overwrite
    .Close
End With
set xmlhttp = nothing
```

Comment: I believe this way would work also.  But I am getting an error: "Write to file failed."

I believe this has to do with permissions more than anything however.

Comment: @Hanny this is not a way, this is what you asked. saving the file on server-side like your PHP code does. so I wrote this. and yes, you're right it could be a permission issue or incorrect path.

Comment: Once I had our server admin adjust permissions - this did exactly what I wanted.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

First of all, installing PHP on IIS isn't that difficult, it might be a better option for you than rewriting everything in Classic ASP

Defining Response.ContentType is important.  Other than that I've never tried this with an image file before so I'm guessing a bit here

Edited - I've tried this and it works.  Save the code below as a separate file - give it a name like mygif.asp

```
<% url = "http://url.to/the/api/thatreturnsagif"       
Set mygif = Server.CreateObject("Msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    mygif.open "GET",url, false
    mygif.send 
    Response.ContentType = "image/gif" 
    Response.binarywrite mygif.ResponseBody

set mygif=nothing %>
```

Then you can embed it with an img tag just as you would embed a flat image.

```
<img src="mygif.asp">
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me it's in an environment where they simply won't allow PHP installation.  So - ASP is what I'm forced to work with (not my first choice, mind you).

I'll give this a shot - thanks!

Comment: This does not work unfortunately.  I'm playing around with it to see what I can get rolling.

Comment: You're right - this works a treat - the reason I wanted to write it to a file however was to keep from pinging my API every time I visited the page (to limit API calls).